# print when a person posts on soundcloud

Tags: python, json, soundcloud

I'm trying to make it alert me (in console, I am later going to add a discord bot to it) whenever my friend posts to SoundCloud, I would preferably like to get the song link and information about it but I cant do that without getting the basics done.

I've looked through SoundCloud API documentation, and the closest to this is to list the songs.

I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a developper but personnaly I would create a database with the actual song of a profile, then check if a new one appeared every x time.

Have you checked really easy solution like Zapier or IFTTT ? They may offer that kind of service. And they can directly make a webhook to a discord bot.